# error handling in php

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a file that opens a URL and reads it and does the parsing.
Now if that URL goes dwon and my file fails to open it then what i need is that an error mail should get generated but on terminal or konsole no error message should appear.
how can i do that?
Plz help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can always do something like this (i'm assuming you are using file_get_contents)

```
$file = @fopen("abc.com","rb");
if(!$file) { 
    @mail(.......); 
    die(); 
} 
//rest of code. Else is not needed since script will die if hit if condition
```

Comment: thats what im doing ,im using @fopen instead of @file_get_contents but what i want is that error should noe appear on terminal/Konsole.By using this kind of code im getting error message on the terminal when i execute it there.I want that no error msg shud appear on termianl.

Comment: "@" sign suppress error messages, probably some other line of code causing echoing of the error. You should post a snippet of your code, otherwise it can be a bit tough to give good advice.

Comment: $flag=0; $file = @fopen("abc.com","rb") or $flag=1; if($flag==1) { mail(.......); die(); } else { .......... } this code is generating the mail the way i want but the problem is that i am getting that error on terminal/konsole as well,which i dont want.What i want is that no error should appear on Terminal/Konsole while executing this file even if the URL is down....I hope u r understanding what im saying........

Comment: there is an ini file setting called display_errors, might want to check if that is on

Answer (score 1):

Use curl instead if you are retrieving files over the network. It has error handling built in and it will tell you the error that occurred. Using file_get_contents won't tell you what went wrong, it also won't follow redirects.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.com/file');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ( $result == false ) {
    $errorInfo = curl_errno($ch).' '.curl_error($ch);
    mail(...)
} else {
    //Process file, $result contains file contents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$content = file_get_contents('http://example.org')) {
  mail(...);
}
```